# The expression "play a geopolitical game of chess"

Tags: idioms

Is this idiomatic? I saw it being used by some people in forums, but never saw any renowned author used this expression. Is there a better way to say it?

For example:

> India was playing a geopolitical game of chess while Pakistan was
>   playing a geopolitical game of checkers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty common to use chess as a metaphor.  It suggests a complex process in which there are two sides, winners and losers, and skill is a significant factor.

It's not a fixed idiom, but this kind of figurative language is common enough.